# Setting up HTTPS/SSL on Amazon EC2 instance and Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have already set up the HTTPS/SSL for my site on Amazon EC2. I checked it on several different SSL checker sites online, and I think it is set up  properly. I'm using Django web framework, so do I  need to follow anything in this spec to make sure I didn't miss  anything? 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/security/#ssl-https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django 1.7 and later have a bit better security and patch most of the possible X-Frames related exploits.

However I personally like to set the security in my NGINX config. A great guide for that is https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html

And for SSL security in general, I recommend https://ssllabs.com